# llama-index unstructured simple directory reader not working

Tags: python, llama-index

I am trying to use `Unstrcutred.io` version of `llama-index` as defined [here](https://github.com/emptycrown/llama-hub/tree/main/loader_hub/file/unstructured)

I have a `pdf` file and a `html` file in my data directory and when I execute, I get following error -

```
File "main.py", line 199, in lddataV2
    SimpleDirectoryReader = download_loader("SimpleDirectoryReader")
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/llama_index/readers/download.py", line 211, in download_loader
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 936, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1073, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1130, in get_data
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/.../venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/llama_index/readers/llamahub_modules/file/base.py'
```

Here is my code:

```
SimpleDirectoryReader = download_loader("SimpleDirectoryReader")

    loader = SimpleDirectoryReader('output_html', file_extractor={
        ".pdf": "UnstructuredReader",
        ".html": "UnstructuredReader"
    })
    documents = loader.load_data()
```

My `llama-index` version `0.6.2` and python `3.11`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
from llama_index import download_loader, SimpleDirectoryReader

UnstructuredReader = download_loader('UnstructuredReader')

dir_reader = SimpleDirectoryReader('./example2', file_extractor={
  ".pdf": UnstructuredReader(),
  ".html": UnstructuredReader(),
})
documents = dir_reader.load_data()

print(documents)
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.